# Joomla 2.5 display wrong custom form field in debian or linux server

Tags: php, joomla

Please help me on this.
I recently created a new Component for Joomla 2.5.
In my component, I have a form and I defined my form using xml in administrator/component//models/form

In this form, I have a custom field. It extends JFormField. It display a list of checkboxes which are loaded from database.

the result is:

In my local computer (running window 7), It displays correctly a list of checkboxes.
However, when I install my component to my server which is running debian or linux, It only shows a text box (input type="text")

Have anybody has any solutions about this? Please ask me, if this is not clear enough.

Thanks in advance

Nathan

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

it is very simple. just change the name of the custom field form to all lowercase not case-camel